# Jest doesn't recognize FileSystemFileHandle createWritable() method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In my code, I am using the relatively new interface of FileSystemFileHandle (documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle/createWritable)

In the documentation, it shows you can just call the createWritable() method, and React knows what to do with it. This would be correct, and my code works. However, when trying to create a test for my new method, Jest thinks createWritable() is not a function. This makes sense, since I didn't have to import any library to use this method.

How can I test my code using createWritable(), or is there any workaround so that the test at least passes?

//code example:

```
this.state = {
handleFile: [] 
};
async fileWriter({ data }) {

//request writable stream
const writer = await this.state.handleFile.createWritable(); 

await writer.write(new Blob([data])); // write the Blob directly

await writer.close(); // end writing

}
```

Comment: You will have to mock probably

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely clear on what needs mocked. Is it my whole function, or just createWritable?

Comment: @troy4gto Did you find a solution for this?